# Default Trace activity object not in database listed

Tags: sql-server

I've been collecting information on the default trace however i've noticed something strange.

Below is a what i'm running ,

```
DECLARE @trc_path VARCHAR (500)

SELECT @trc_path = CONVERT(VARCHAR (500), value)
FROM   fn_trace_getinfo(DEFAULT)
WHERE  property = 2

SELECT StartTime,
       ObjectName,
       DatabaseName,
       (SELECT name
        FROM   sys. trace_events
        WHERE  trace_event_id = fn.eventclass) AS EventClass,
       ObjectType,
       ServerName,
       LoginName,
       ApplicationName,
       HostName
FROM   :: fn_trace_gettable(@trc_path, DEFAULT) AS fn
WHERE  EventClass IN ( 46, 47, 164 )
       AND EventSubclass = 0
```

I've noticed something strange, I collected some data which suggested there was an alteration to a stored procedure that wasn't in the database listed, it was a stored procedured which lived in a different database. Initially I thought the database listed is the trace data was the the default database of the user running the process but then i saw in another trace collected this wasn't the case.

Can anyone explain why a database might be associated to a foreign stored procedure alter?

Thanks !